# How to cancel all blank pages between chapters?

Tags: chapters, blank-page

Here is my document from the beginning:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}



\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  

\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}
%\bibliography{references}
```

Here is the part of my code that I doubt it gives me those blank pages:

```
 \newcommand{\page}[1]{\rightskip=25pt \dotfill\rlap{\hbox to 25pt{\hfill#1}}\par}
  \doublespacing 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}
```

Any advice about how to delete blank pages from between chapters please?

Comment: Oh sorry, I will edit my post ..... yes it is book @Teepeemm

Comment: @Teepeemm Done! ..... I do not understand where I am using `openany` in my code.

Comment: What @Teepeemm means is to add `openany` to your document class options: `\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `book` document class opens chapters only on odd numbered pages.  If you want to allow it to open chapters on even numbered pages, you would pass the `openany` option to the class:
`\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}`

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much!